# Jplayer won't play html5 video

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, firefox, jplayer

I went to https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/examples/pink.flag/demo-02-video.html and copy and pasted the code from the example and made a simple `node.js` server to serve the page. However the video does not play. Instead I get the warning, `Update Required To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your Flash plugin.`

I have the newest browsers so shouldn't `html5` work and I thought the point of `flash` in `jplayer` was to support older browsers that don't support `html5`. So why won't `jplayer` play on the newest versions of `firefox`, `chrome`, and `safari` on `Mac OSX 10.10.3`?

Here is a list of browsers I tried, note, chrome canary is the official nightly build from google.

chrome canary version 45.0.2451.0

normal chrome 43.0.2357.132

firefox 39.0

safari 8.0.6

I also tried with safari on my iphone running `IOS 8.4`

But `jplayer` does not play on any of these browsers.